# SoapClient fatal error Magento SOAP API

Tags: php, codeigniter, magento, soap, cron

I'm trying to run a method i created on Codeigniter and run it via Cli Cron

Cron line: php /home/path/to/ci/index.php controller method

inside the method i have a a SoapClient function that connect to a Magento webservices, running it on the web works like charm, but running on Cron with php it give me this error:

```
Type: SoapFaultMessage: SoapClient::SoapClient(): 'uri' option is required in nonWSDL modeFilename:

Type: SoapFaultMessage: SoapClient::SoapClient(): 'location' option is required in nonWSDL modeFilename:
```

As i understand it needs an uri and location in the SoapClient function.

i added this 2 parameters but it still need one more, and i don't know what parameter is:

```
Type: SoapFaultMessage: Required parameter is missing
```

is there a way to create a SoapClient with nonWSDL for Magento?

Magento connection:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.magento.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1', array('trace' => true, 'uri' => 'urn:Magento', 'location' => 'http://www.magento.com/api/'));
$session = $client->login('userApi', 'apiKey');
$getAttributes = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product_attribute.options', '11');
var_dump($getAttributes );
$client->endSession($session);
```

XML Soap Structure:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Magento" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
<types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
<!--
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
-->
<complexType name="FixedArray">
<complexContent>
<restriction base="soapenc:Array">
<attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]"/>
</restriction>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
</schema>
</types>
<message name="call">
<part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="resourcePath" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="args" type="xsd:anyType"/>
</message>
<message name="callResponse">
<part name="callReturn" type="xsd:anyType"/>
</message>
<message name="multiCall">
<part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="calls" type="typens:FixedArray"/>
<part name="options" type="xsd:anyType"/>
</message>
<message name="multiCallResponse">
<part name="multiCallReturn" type="typens:FixedArray"/>
</message>
<message name="endSession">
<part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="endSessionResponse">
<part name="endSessionReturn" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</message>
<message name="login">
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="apiKey" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="loginResponse">
<part name="loginReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="resources">
<part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="resourcesResponse">
<part name="resourcesReturn" type="typens:FixedArray"/>
</message>
<message name="globalFaults">
<part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="globalFaultsResponse">
<part name="globalFaultsReturn" type="typens:FixedArray"/>
</message>
<message name="resourceFaults">
<part name="resourceName" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="resourceFaultsResponse">
<part name="resourceFaultsReturn" type="typens:FixedArray"/>
</message>
<message name="startSession"/>
<message name="startSessionResponse">
<part name="startSessionReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPortType">
<operation name="call">
<documentation>Call api functionality</documentation>
<input message="typens:call"/>
<output message="typens:callResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="multiCall">
<documentation>Multiple calls of resource functionality</documentation>
<input message="typens:multiCall"/>
<output message="typens:multiCallResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="endSession">
<documentation>End web service session</documentation>
<input message="typens:endSession"/>
<output message="typens:endSessionResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="login">
<documentation>Login user and retrive session id</documentation>
<input message="typens:login"/>
<output message="typens:loginResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="startSession">
<documentation>Start web service session</documentation>
<input message="typens:startSession"/>
<output message="typens:startSessionResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="resources">
<documentation>List of available resources</documentation>
<input message="typens:resources"/>
<output message="typens:resourcesResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="globalFaults">
<documentation>List of resource faults</documentation>
<input message="typens:globalFaults"/>
<output message="typens:globalFaultsResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="resourceFaults">
<documentation>List of global faults</documentation>
<input message="typens:resourceFaults"/>
<output message="typens:resourceFaultsResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBinding" type="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPortType">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="call">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="multiCall">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="endSession">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="login">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="startSession">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="resources">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="globalFaults">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="resourceFaults">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="MagentoService">
<port name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPort" binding="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBinding">
<soap:address location="https://www.magento.com/index.php/api/soap/index/"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: do you see the wsdl definition when you go to http://www.magento.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1 ??

Comment: Yes, i see all XML structure there.

Comment: I added the Structure to the post

Comment: Try with this SoapClient https://www.mikemackintosh.com/fixing-soap-exception-no-xml/

Comment: In my case how will be applied this?

Comment: I think everything is completely fine, you should try other software stacks on your end since it seems the problem is there and not on magento or your code. SoapCliente(wsdl) should work fine. good luck